# useState creating multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am creating a dropdown filter to update the search results of a page using react hooks. Basically, I am passing an array with the options that the user chose from the dropdown menu. I am successfully updating the global state with the new arrays BUT my issue is useState creates a NEW array instead of merging the results with the previous state.
[image]

Above you can see, I made two calls with different filter options and the global state now holds 2 arrays. My goal is to have both arrays merged into one.

This is the function where the global state is being updated.

```
const Results = () => {
    const [filterList, setFilterList] = useState([])

    const setGlobalFilter = (newFilter) => {
        let indexFilter = filterList.indexOf(newFilter);

        // console.log("Top level index", indexFilter)

        indexFilter ?
        setFilterList([...new Set([...filterList, newFilter])]) :
        setFilterList(filterList => filterList.filter((filter, i) => i !== indexFilter))
    }

    // console.log("TopFilterSelection:", filterList)
    return (
        <div>
            <Filter setFilter={(filterList) => setGlobalFilter(filterList)}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've been checking on using prevState like this:

```
...
        setFilterList(prevState => [...new Set([...prevState, newFilter])]) :
...
```

But I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `newFilter`is an array, not a word.
Should be

```
setFilterList(previous => [...new Set([...previous, ...newFilter])])
```

Also this

```
let indexFilter = filterList.indexOf(newFilter);
```

always returns -1 if `newFilter`is an array (since you a sending brand new array each time), it's not a falsy value, be careful

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.concat` method.

```
setFilterList(filterList.concat(newFilter))
```

Read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat